# Comparing one .txt file to a folder of .txt files in Powershell

Tags: regex, shell, powershell

I am attempting to compare one .txt file to multiple .txt files using Powershell. The first .txt file looks something like this:

```
x1
x2
x3
...
x250
```

The other files are all exactly in this format:

```
uses 'x1'
uses 'x5'
uses 'x34'
```

... and so on.

Here is the script I have written to go about this:

```
$lines = Get-Content C:\Users\user1\Documents\permfile.txt
$files = Get-Content "C:\Users\user1\Documents\AppFiles\"

foreach($file in $files){
  Get-Content $file
  foreach($line in $lines){
    $permmatch = Where-Object {$line -CIn $file}
    if ($permmatch -CNotContains $line) {
      Write-Output "0, `n" >> C:\Users\user1\Object\binary.txt
    } 
    else {
      Write-Output Write-Host "1, `n" >> C:\Users\user1\Object\binary.txt
    }
  }
  Write-Output "; `n" >> C:\Users\user1\Object\binary.txt
}
```

The goal is to create a new file that mimics file 1 line-by-line, with "1," in place of every line which is also in the AppFile (file 2), and "0," in place of every line that does not. Once a given AppFile has been completely compared to file 1, a ; will mark the beginning of the same comparison for the next AppFile.

Using the example file 2, which contains x1, x5, and x34, this is what the output file would look like:

```
1,
0,
0,
0,
1,
...
1, (line 34)
...
0, (line 250)
;
```

Yet for some reason, whenever I run the script, I get no 1's. Only 0's for each line. What is the reason for this? Am I simply using the Get-Content or Where-Object cmdlets incorrectly? Any response or assistance is appreciated.

Comment: In the example you list, would you expect the output to start with 3 `1`s or 2 `1`s and a `0`?

Comment: Yes, please provide example output and make sure that your example output and example input cover all the edge cases that you anticipate.

Comment: The example file 2 contains 'x1', 'x5', and 'x34'. Ideally, the output file for this would look like: "1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,;" with spaces after each comma.

Comment: Please add new information by editing your question.

Comment: And the "AppFiles" are always in the exact same format? ie `uses '[string to compare]'`?

Comment: Yes, they are all in the same format. I edited my post to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the `-Contains` operator is not made for substring comparisons and but only matches a complete string (in a collection, etc).

> -Contains Description: Containment operator. Tells whether a collection of reference values includes a single test value. [Ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx)

What you need is the `-Match` operator.
Alternatively, you could use the `.Contains()` .NET String method.

Try it like this:

```
$lines = Get-Content C:\Users\user1\Documents\permfile.txt
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\user1\Documents\AppFiles\" -Recurse -Include *.*

foreach($file in $files) {
  $content = Get-Content $file
  foreach($line in $lines) {
    $permmatch = $content -Match $line.Trim()
    if ($permmatch.Length -eq 0) {
      ....
```